# Where to put files for Java project to access them in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, text-files

I'm making a project which involves creating a lot of objects of various classes, some repeatedly. I would like to be able to have my program read from files to decide how to create them. Where should I put these files in the Eclipse project package in order to have them accessible by the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially the files can be anywhere in your project, as long as you know where to look for them.

Here is an example setup of a project

[image: file directory]

To retrieve the files located in "stocks", one can access them like so

```
    public void loadStocks() {
        for (File file : new File("stocks").listFiles()) {
            this.stockFiles.add(file);
        }
    }
```

This, specifically, will cycle through all the files located in the "stocks" folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can put those files in the documents.It can work..but better you mention the path of their locations to make them access with ease.